# cmake use outside libraries "together" "on demand"

Tags: c++, c, cmake

exsample:I download zlib,put into a dir and not compile.
then create a project try use zlib:

```
project(hello) 

SET(MODULE_PATH C:/modules)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${MODULE_PATH}/zlib-1.2.8) 


add_library(zlib STATIC ${MODULE_PATH}/zlib-1.2.8) 

add_executable(hello hello.cpp) 

target_link_libraries(hello zlib)
```

not work(cmake for vs2015 NMake):cannot determine link language for target "zlib".
what's wrong? How can I use libraries on demand(do not need precompile)

.............ok,I get close to...I hope so
this is my dir:

zlib in F:\cmake\modules\zlib-1.2.8

test project in F:\cmake\test1

this my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(hello)
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
SET(MODULE_PATH ../modules)
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${MODULE_PATH})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${MODULE_PATH}/zlib-1.2.8)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(libs)
add_subdirectory(${MODULE_PATH}/zlib-1.2.8 libs)
add_executable(hello hello.cpp)
target_link_libraries(hello  zlib)
```

now I can complie nmake or mingw32-make success !

but...seem to  set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF) have  no effects:zlib gen dll and static lib and mingw auto link dll lib. 
I don't want to change target_link_libraries(hello  zlib) to
target_link_libraries(hello  libzlibstatic.a) because nmake's project  is not this name....

now how can I improve this for ideally only need cmake..nmake/ming32-make/make(Borland's)?

Comment: You have never defined any source files for your `zlib` target. When using existing 3rd-party libraries within your CMake projects have a look at the [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/module/ExternalProject.html) module.

Comment: seem  to ExternalProject must define concrete command:BUILD_COMMAND...INSTALL_COMMAND... but I want to:cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" =>build vc project auto.....and cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" =>build mingw project auto. use  External (have CMakelists.txt)library config auto

Comment: `How can I use libraries on demand(do not need precompile)` - Before actual linking (at *build* stage), the library file should be created. As noted by Torbjörn, you may create the library file at build stage with use of `ExternalProject_Add`. But on *configuration* stage (when `CMakeLists.txt` is processed) you need to provide **exact path to the library file**, which will be created on building. For that purpose you may use that path directly in `target_link_libraries` call, or create *IMPORTED* library target and use it.